# Retrofit Android Gson deserializer date inside json

Tags: android, json, gson, deserialization, retrofit

I have the following problem:
The answers to my API are always like this "style":

```
{
  "type": "dbUserResponse",
  "user": {
    "apellido": "canadas",
    "email": "rj@canada.es",
    "nacimiento": "1995-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
  }
}
```

That is, field "dbXXXXResponse" and model. That is, field "Response" and model. In this case user. Another example for the model Alert:

```
{
  "type": "dbAlertResponse",
  "alert": {
    "alertId": 0,
    "fecha": "2004-10-19T10:23:54+02:00",
  }
}
```

Oki... What I need? Create a type Adapter deserialize or more?
One generic, or I have to make one typedapter for each model.
I have done the following:

```
    public class GenericDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T>
    {
@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException
{
    // Get the "content" element from the parsed JSON
    JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("type");


    if(content.toString().equals("\"dbUserResponse\"")){
        content = je.getAsJsonObject().get("user");

        JsonObject jsonObject = content.getAsJsonObject();
        if(jsonObject.has("nacimiento")){
            String date = jsonObject.get("nacimiento").getAsString();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = sdf.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date2);
            jsonObject.addProperty("nacimiento", newstring);
            content = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject();  
            }
        }

    }
    if(content.toString().equals("\"dbAlertResponse\"")){
    // other case..... etc...

    }

    else{
        //content = '{"error":"mierror"}';
    }


    // Deserialize it. You use a new instance of Gson to avoid infinite recursion
    // to this deserializer
    return new Gson().fromJson(content, type);

}
}
```

Thus, I have managed to successfully obtain the sub JSON "user" and fill my User model in Android.
But the "nacimiento" (date) field is not formatted :-(

I have also created a Singleton Retrofit, I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
public class SingletonRetrofit {

public static final String BASE_URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new GenericDeserializer<User>())
                    .create();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

**My questions:
1º- How correctly format the date when the model is inside another Json Json like me?
2º- Will I have to create a typeadapter for each model? : -S
Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use POJO? Date in JSON is String so you must convert String to Date.

Comment: I user POJO, when say Model. when he said model, I meant to pojo USER.
How convert String to Date?????

and once this in Date, as I apply the format "yyyy-mm-dd"????

Comment: If you use POJO you should download data from API, Retrofit should parse data to POJO class and you can get object as String from response.

Comment: Yes, but my field "nacimiento" Always it appears with a format that I do not want.
It appears that in this format: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT + 00: 00 1995.
I want to appear only this: 01-01-1995

Comment: You have to format Date. You know original format of date. `1995-01-01T00:00:00+01:00` YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS TZ and you should format to "yyyy-mm-dd". If you use MVP you should format in your presenter. The way is: Presenter gets data from Model. Presenter formats date as you wany and presenter pass data to view.